# Numpy I want to add numbers to my for loops when it reaches row 5

Tags: python, numpy, for-loop, if-statement

I am trying to add 1,2,3,4,5 after the fourth role which means I want to add numbers starting from row 5 of my 10x10 arrays. Below Attached with my code.

```
big_arr = np.zeros((10,10),dtype=np.uint8)
count = 0
for x in range(0,10):
    for y in range(0,10):
        if big_arr[x,y] > 50:
            big_arr[x,y] = count + 1
            count += 1
```

Im not sure why the value of big_arr[x,y] is 0 and if i switch the operator to < it will then add 1 continuously. Aren't the value will be adding after the row and columns reach 50? Thank you

Comment: It's not clear from your code what and description what you're trying to do. If you could provide examples of reduced dimension of your input arrays and the expected output it would be much clearer.

Comment: @xvan I have an 10x10 arrays of 0 and I want the value of row 5 onwards become 1,2,3,4,5 and so on.

Comment: @xvan feel free to check out my latest answer and I guess u will know what I am trying to do. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're working on numpy, and doing for loops, you're most likely doing something wrong.

The speed of numpy achieved through [slicing](https://www.w3schools.com/python/numpy/numpy_array_slicing.asp) .

```
import numpy as np

my_array=np.zeros((10,10))
print(my_array)

#[[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
# [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
# [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
# [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
# [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
# [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
# [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
# [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
# [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
# [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]

fill_array = np.arange(1,51).reshape(5,10)
print(fill_array)

#[[ 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10]
# [11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20]
# [21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30]
# [31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40]
# [41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50]]

my_array[5:,:] = fill_array
print(my_array)


#[[ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
# [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
# [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
# [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
# [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
# [ 1.  2.  3.  4.  5.  6.  7.  8.  9. 10.]
# [11. 12. 13. 14. 15. 16. 17. 18. 19. 20.]
# [21. 22. 23. 24. 25. 26. 27. 28. 29. 30.]
# [31. 32. 33. 34. 35. 36. 37. 38. 39. 40.]
# [41. 42. 43. 44. 45. 46. 47. 48. 49. 50.]]
```

Comment: Note that you can directly do `my_array[5:,:].flat = np.arange(1,51)` ;)

Comment: Thanks for providing me another way of approach. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Hello I just found out the answer.

```
big_arr = np.zeros((10,10),dtype=np.uint8)
count = 0
for x in range(5,10):
    for y in range(0,10):
        big_arr[x,y] = count + 1
        count += 1
```

All I did was changing the range in x to 5 and the value starts kicking in. Thank you.

Comment: But it's a bad approach for numpy, use vectorial indexing like in the other answer.